# Can ctags differentiate between different symbols with same name?

Tags: c, vim, ctags, cscope

I am trying to use vim together with ctags and/or cscope and it works quite nice but I have some problems where ctags jumps to the wrong symbol. For example in the code below, if I place my the cursor over symbol "a" in main() and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to go to the definition I will be directed to the "char a" in my "dummy struct" but I want to be directed to my "int a" in main. Can ctags or cscope handle this or do the symbols need unique names?

```
struct dummy
{
   char a;
};

int main ()
{
   int a = 1;
   a = a + 2;
   return a;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, ctags handles this by putting all alternatives into the tags file; you can open the `tags` file to verify this.

Your problem is caused by the behavior of the `<C-]>` command; from `:help CTRL-]`:

> When there are several matching tags for {ident}, jump
>     to the [count] one.  When no [count] is given the
>     first one is jumped to. See |tag-matchlist| for
>     jumping to other matching tags.

You can either supply a `[count]` before the command (first jump back to the original position after a wrong tag jump via `<C-t>`), or use the `:tselect` command instead, which lists all tag alternatives and queries which one to jump to.

Comment: Ok, so ctag won't know if my variable is the local variable or if it is the member of my struct? I will always have to look at the list by myself?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Vim just gets a list of matching tags, as a text editor, it doesn't know the syntax, and lets you choose the appropriate one.

Comment: Ok, I think that was the answer I was looking for then. Do you know if there is any tool that could handle this problem? I am trying to move from Eclipse to vim and this is one thing I miss when working in vim.

Comment: Vim is a powerful text editor, not an IDE. You can use both, and easily switch files between them; I do so with IntelliJ IDEA, too.

Comment: Note: instead of `:tselect` it is also possible to do `g<C-]>`.

Answer (score 1):

When Multiple symbols are present with the same name(what you are searching for!), it will display all the possibilities on your screen, and option to go there. see the below example(that from my code!)

```
1 mcasttx.c      4 #include <sys/socket.h>
2 mcasttx.c     11 int socket_id,nbytes,newsocket_id;
3 mcasttx.c     22 socket_id=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
4 mcasttx.c     23 if(socket_id == -1){
5 mcasttx.c     24 printf("Failed to Create a socket\n");
6 mcasttx.c     32 if(bind(socket_id,(struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr))<0){
7 mcasttx.c     37 if( listen(socket_id, 5) < 0){
```

it will display like this you can go to any line by pressing appropriate line number!